Azure Files with Private Endpoint over Azure VPN
I setup an Azure Files storage account with Public access disabled and an internal Private Endpoint address of 10.0.0.4 and the provided PrivateLink DNS enabled.
I also have a Virtual Network Gateway with Point to Site connections using Azure VPN
If I connect to the Azure VPN from a Remote Client, I am able to PsPing 10.0.0.4:443 successfully (on why Azure decided to block ICMP that's another irritating story) anyway the problem lies with the mapping of such storage account, my understanding is that only works with fqdn and my DNS resolution points to the disabled Public IP access, no good.
To overcome, I setup a DNS Private Resolver, this operates on a different Vnet address space (172.16.0.0/21) which has two subnets for Inbound Endpoint (172.16.5.0/28) and for Outbound Endpoint (172.16.6.0/28). Upon launching the DNS Private Resolver it gets an address of 172.16.5.4 which I can then add as DNS Server to my main VNet (where the VNG, Storage Account sits on) so that Azure VPN default to this DNS Server at the client level.
This is where my luck ends, I can't map this drive by using either the fqdn or the PrivateLink fqdn, the DNS records in Azure do point to the Private Endpoint IP however the lack of knowing how to troubleshoot makes it difficult, I try PsPing or Ping to 172.16.5.4 and I get no replies, should I get any? I dunno. Is that interface even pingable so to speak?
I thought that the reason could be because the main vnet (10.0.0.0/16) and the DNS Private Resolver VNet (172.16.0.0/8) could not communicate being separate Vnets so I added Vnet Peering between the two.
This didn't help either.
Any kind soul that can help fix this?

To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps.

The Private DNS Zone must be linked to the VNET which has the private DNS resolver.



Make sure there are no DNS Forwarding rule sets linked to the VNET in which the private DNS resolver resides.

VNET peering between the Private DNS Resolver VNET and Gateway VNET is required.



I created VNET1 with 3 subnets and used 2 subnets in the private DNS resolver. Then, I created VNET2 and peered VNET1 to VNET2.
I have added A record in Private DNS zone, as below.

DNS Private resolver Inbound endpoint

DNS Private resolver outbound endpoint

After implementing the above configuration, I am now able to resolve the DNS from the VM

And for P2S, you need additional set up as well.
1.Add DNS suffixes and Add custom DNS servers
2. dnssuffix should be the DNS Domain name (FQDN)
3.  dnsserver should be inbound IP of Private DNS
References:

Configure Azure VPN Client optional settings - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn
Resolve Azure and on-premises domains

